# Refactoring using decorators to reduce code volume

Tags: python, selenium, nose

i've recently switch to a new project and all our selenium tests are written in Python. I was wondering if i can reduce the code volume by using decorators

what we got right now is :

```
class BasePage(object):
    view_button = ".//a[text()='View']"
    create_button = ".//a[text()='Create']"
    #some code here

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    setUpclass(cls):
    #code here

    def find(cls,xpath):
        return cls.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)


class SomeTest(BaseTestCase):
    def test_00_something(self):
        self.find(self.view_button).click()
```

I'm thinking is there a way to minimize that whole`self.find(self.view_button).click()` into something like `click.view_button`

I heard it could be done using decorators, but being a Java person I had little success with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also check the following solution; Create new module - navigation.py with :

```
class Button():

    def __init__(self,driver, locator):
        self.driver = driver
        self.locator = locator

    @property
    def click(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.locator).click()

class Navigation():

    """NAVIGATION COMMANDS """
    def goTo(self):
        #somethign

    def previousPage(self):
        #something

    """ BUTTONS """
    @property
    def view_button(self):
        xpath = ".//a[text()='View']"
        view = Button(self.driver,xpath)
        return view

   @property
   def create_button(self):
       xpath = ".//a[text()='Create']"
       create = Button(self.driver,xpath)
       return create
```

In basetestcase.py:

```
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase, Navigation)

      setUpClass(cls):
      #somethign here
```

and your test case would look the following way:

```
class TestSomething(BaseTestCase):

     def test_99_somethign(self):
         #finds .//a[text()='View'] and clicks
         self.view.click

         #create button
         self.create_button.click
```

This way, you will be able to use navigation class inside your test. Plus you keep all of you navigation elements in one place

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would make it so you can do `click.view_button`. However, you could give you element its own class. This way you can achieve something like `view_button.click()`. In my project I am doing this for all my elements.

```
class BaseElement:
    def __init__(self, driver, locator):
        self.driver = driver
        self.locator = locator

    def get(self):
        self.driver.find_element(locator)

    def click():
        self.get().click()


class ViewButton(BaseElement):
    def __init__(self, driver):
       locator = (By.XPATH, ".//a[text()='View']")
       super(ViewButton, self).__init__(driver, locator)


class BasePage(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.view_button = ViewButton(driver)


class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    setUpclass(cls):
        # driver stuff
        self.page = BasePage(driver)


class SomeTest(BaseTestCase):
    def test_00_something(self):
        self.page.view_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to post from RemcoW i found a solution, see below

```
class ViewButton():

    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.locator = (".//a[text()='View']")

    @property
    def click(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.locator).click()

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    #some code here

    @property
    def view(self):
        view = ViewButton(self.driver)
        return view
```

in test cases it works like this

```
class TestThign(BaseTestCase):

    def test_00_something(self):
        self.view.click
```